# How can I remove all tag's attributes except specific ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this string:

```
var str = '<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>';
```

I want to remove all attributes except `href`, `src`, `alt`. So this is expected result:

```
/* 
<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
<div>
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
    <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
    <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
    <b>bold</b>
    <img src="../path" alt="something">
    <img src="../path" alt="something">
</div>
```

How can I do that?

---

I can just select them which isn't useful:

[`/<[a-z]+ .*?(href|src|alt)="[^"]+"/g`](https://regex101.com/r/bB31js/1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @epascarello ok, how should I parse HTML then in JS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var str = `<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>`;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
div.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(el){
  for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    var att = atts[i].nodeName;
    if (["src","alt","href"].indexOf(att) ==-1) el.removeAttribute(att); 
  }
}); 
// console.log(div); alert shows it more clearly
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

PS: Please note that you need backticks to quote a string with embedded newlines

Comment: just one thing, why have you used `<div>` tag? What happens if my string also be containing `<div>` tag?

Comment: @MartinAJ `<div>` is just a container for your HTML (`div`s can have other `div`s inside them). A problem could occur if your `str` contains a `body` or `html` tag.

Comment: You could use `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New").body` 
 instead of `document.createElement("div")`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = `<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>`;
var $div =$("<div>");
$div.html(str);
  $div.find("*").each(function() {

    var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });

    // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
    var element = $(this);
    $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
      if (["href", "src", "alt"].indexOf(item) == -1)
        element.removeAttr(item);
    });


  });
console.log($div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```