# How can I remove a tag which contains every attribute except specific ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
var str = `<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>`;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
div.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(el){
  for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    var att = atts[i].nodeName;
    if (["src","alt","href"].indexOf(att) ==-1) el.removeAttribute(att); 
  }
}); 
// console.log(div); alert shows it more clearly
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

It removes every attribute except `src`, `alt`, `href`. Now I want to remove the tag *(not just the attribute)* which contains any attribute except those three ones.

I've tested `removeChild()` instead of `removeAttribute()`, but it doesn't work as expected. Any idea?

---

An short example:

input:

```
<a href="#" class="sth">link</a>
<img src="#" />
```

expected output:

```
link
<img src="#" />
```

`<a>` should be removed, because of `class` attribute.

Comment: jquery's unwrap? https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: @Snowmonkey Maybe. I will check it out. thank you

Comment: Did you try removeChild on the div? It's `div.removeChild(el)`, not `el.removeChild()` ALso, if you update your querySelectorAll, you could select only all the elements containing one of those attributes and just remove all of them.

Comment: @Shilly Why should I select *all the elements containing one of those attributes* ?

Comment: @MartinAJ doesn't want to remove el's children, simply (from what I can see) to remove the el itself and keep the children in the tree structure.

Comment: must have all 3 or just remove if any other attributes exist?

Comment: @charlietfl *just remove if any other attributes exist.*

Comment: To get the reverse of it obv, so you can just removeChild loop over them.

Comment: If element has `src`, `alt`, `href`, remove tag?

Comment: @guest271314 all together, yes! but `src` + `alt`, no!

Comment: @guest271314 by the way, a tag which has those three attributes, seems invalid to me!

Comment: Could you clarify the exact rules when an element has to be removed, since it's getting confusing now. Also, removing the tag removes the innerHTML, so does that innerHTML have to be reinserted as text after the tag is removed? (As you show in your desired output.)

Comment: If `alt` and `src` attributes but not `href` do not remove tag? Why would  element have both `src` and `href` attributes at same element?

Comment: @guest271314 no,that's ok. Here is the idea:  All tags should be removed if they have any attribute. Except the ones which have either `href` attribute or `src` attribute. noted that `alt` is also allowed if comes next to `src` attribute. that's it. cc @Shilly

Comment: _"noted that `alt` is also allowed if comes next to `src` attribute."_ What should occur where both `alt` and `src` attributes are present?

Comment: @guest271314 all tags should be removed except these: 1. only `href` attribute. 2. only `src` attribute. 3. both `src` and `alt` attributes. 4. there isn't any attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.each()`, `.children()`, `.is()`, `.filter()`, `.replaceWith()`

```js
var str = `<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>`;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;
$(div).children().each(function (_, el) {
    if (!$(">[src], >[href]", el).length) {      
      $(el).children().add(el).each(function(_, element) {
         $(element).replaceWith(element.textContent)
      });
    } else {
      $(el).children().each(function(_, elem) {
        if (!$(">[src], >[href]", elem).length 
            && !$(elem).is("[href], [src]")) {
          $(elem).replaceWith(elem.innerHTML);
        } else {
          if ($(">[href], >[src]", elem).length)
           $(elem).filter(function(_, element) {
             return !$(element).is("[href], [src]")
           }).replaceWith(elem.innerHTML);
        }
      });     
      if (!$(el).is("[href], [src]")) {
        $(el).replaceWith(el.innerHTML)
      }    
    }
  });
  // console.log(div); alert shows it more clearly
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = `<p>paragraph<a>link</a></p>
           <div class="myclass">
               <div>something</div>
               <div style="mystyle">something</div>
               <b><a href="#">link</a></b>
               <b><a href="#" name="a name">link</a></b>
               <b style="color:red">bold</b>
               <img src="../path" alt="something" />
               <img src="../path" alt="something" class="myclass" />
           </div>`;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
div.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(el){
  for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    var att = atts[i].nodeName;
    if (["src","alt","href"].indexOf(att) ==-1){
      var parent = el.parentElement;
      while(el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
      parent.removeChild(el);
      break; // element is already removed, don't loop over attributes of a removed element.
    } 
  }
}); 
// console.log(div); alert shows it more clearly
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

Comment: You might want to add a `break` at the end of the `if` block so that the same element is not removed twice (which might lead to errors)

Comment: @Editor you should understand what the code does before wrongly editing it. The code should move all the element inside `el` first then removes `el`. that's why the while doesn't have braces so it can have only one instruction inside it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir right. sorry about setting the braces wrongly :-S

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Plus it should be `break` not `continue` to terminate the `for` loop at once.

Comment: You'll have to slice the nodeList returned from querySelectorAll into an array before looping with forEach for slightly older browsers. Also note that this also removes the wrapper div with myClass, so watch out for your css and layout. But +1 otherwise.

Comment: @Shilly the div with the style attribute is intended to be removed. Since it's not included in `["href", "src", "alt"]`.

Comment: Indeed. I'm mentioning it as a reminder for the OP that this operation might change the layout.

Comment: @Shilly [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923316/how-can-i-remove-all-tags-attributes-except-specific-ones) is the original question asked by him yesterday. In that question he wants just to remove the attributes (style included). Now instead of removing the attributes, he wants to remove the whole element. (:D I witnessed both questions that's why I'm familiar with his needs).

Comment: `<p>`, `<a>`, `<div>`, `<b>` are still included within result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

`div.removeChild(el)`

Comment: This will remove its content as well.